# VB.net add button to form

Tags: vb.net

I have a loop where I want to add a button every time the loop iterates...

I have this above my while:

```
Dim mybut As New Button
Dim btn_number As Integer = 0
```

I have this within my while:

```
btn_number += 1
mybut.AutoSize = True
mybut.Name = "delete-btn" & btn_number
mybut.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(77, 112)
mybut.Text = "Delete"
With mybut.Controls
.Add(mybut)
End With
```

But I get an error message... It's on danish, so I have a little trouble translating it to english, I'm sorry.... But it's something about an object that is referring to itself in a loop...

Hope some of you can spot the issue.... It's possible that I'm writing this all wrong...
Thanks.

Comment: If btn_number is locally declared then that could be the problem. Kindly include the loop and where you declare the btn_number variable.

Comment: Well I've tried to remove my btn_number in all places in the script, but doesn't make any difference, so I don't think that's the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add the button to its own controls (as you do with `mybut.Controls.Add(mybut)`).
You have to add it to some container's controls collection, which might be the form itself (`Me.Controls.Add`)

```
mybut = New Button
btn_number += 1
With mybut
    mybut.AutoSize = True
    mybut.Name = "delete-btn" & btn_number
    mybut.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(77, 112 + 
                btn_number * (mybut.height + 5))
    mybut.Text = "Delete"
End With
Me.Controls.Add(mybut)
```

You probably also want to change the position for each button - as shown here.

As for your edit:
Put this above the loop: `Dim mybut As Button`
And this inside the loop: `mybut = New Button`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you trying to `.Add(mybut)` to `mybut.Controls`.

If you are using this code in a loop, you must also consider change the `.Location` of every button created.